# JQuery UI Attaching a draggable top a specific droppable on page load

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

Is there a simple way to programmatically "bind" a draggable to a droppable on load?

I am trying to create a JIRA like dashboard, where the draggable is attached to a specific droppable and highlights the box to pull to or the box that it is/was associated with. This part works great for the initial dashboard setup, but when I save positions and reload I can do a set position to get the draggable over the droppable target but it doesn't seem bind to the it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone has already solved the problem and provided a script: http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/127_iNETTUTS/demo/index.html

Works great and mimicd exactly what I wanted to do.